# How do you register an onclick event while having onmouseover using Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, onmouseover

I have a function that tracks the user's mouse to show them visually where they are on an x,y grid. When the user's mouse is over the image, a function is called via `onmouseover="gridFunction();"`.

The problem is that I want to record the user's click (`onclick` or `onmousedown`) as they move around the grid image. So I'm trying to stack an `onclick` with an `onmouseover`.

Any suggestions?
I tried creating `document.onclick = "clickFunction();"` but for some odd reason this never gets called when I click on the website (even when I'm not hovering over the image).

Comment: Do you actually call it with the comments around the function? Silly point I know, but you never know. Also, do you include the brackets, they shouldn't be there either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend using [jQuery's events api](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) - it is very easy to use and will more than likely be able to handle your situation.